# Push up view when Edit-Text is selected

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I know there are lot of questions and answers for similar cases but what i couldn't find was. The view in activity is pushed up as cursor goes underneath the keypad. What i want to do is whenever the edit-text is selected and if it is underneath the keypad it will be pushed up. And my edit-text is multi-lined and its height is 300dp. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough to me, but I suggest that you wrap the whole layout in a ScrollView or NestedScrollView depending on the container. It will be automatically pushed up to the focused view.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Add this line in your manifest file in activity's tag and check if it works.